# Is there any way to find out if any alteration is done to any table?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server and a database has too many tables. I am preparing the list of tables which have been recently modified.

Is there any way to find out which tables are modified?

I am interested in knowing:

- if any datatypes are modified to any columns,
- new column is added,
- any column is deleted.

**Note**
The answers below shows tables which has been modified but do not give enough information of what changes has been done to the tables.

Comment: [DDL auditing](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-audit-feature-ddl-event-auditing-examples/), or you could log changes from the system tables yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `modify_date` column in either the `sys.tables` or `sys.all_objects` (with `type = 'U'` for user table) system views.  The below query will work, note that this cast defaults to midnight.

```
select name from sys.all_objects where type = 'U' and
modify_date >= cast('2018-08-22' as datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but how do I know what columns are added or deleted?

Answer (score 2):

If you have not recently restarted your server, the default trace may have some info. In SSMS go to your DB, right click select reports -> Standard Reports -> "Schema Changes History", that should give you the changes on the DB, as long as there's info on your default trace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have followed as you suggested. I can see list of tables and procedures but how can I know what all changes has been done to a table. I can only create,drop or alter under DDL Operation

Comment: If you need that kind of detail, you may need to implement a DDL trigger, in that case you can set the behavior to capture the old structure and the new structure.

Comment: please guide me how to implement trigger

Comment: [This should help](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a53f1a/triggers-in-sql-server/). But this will help you with future alteration on your objects. You will not get any changes that were done in past.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments to implement trigger. I would suggest you to create DDL triggers for tracking DDL changes.
One out of box solution for this is you can implement the scripts by David Rueter 
which he explains [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Version+Control+Systems+(VCS)/119029/)
I have implemented this in dev and test servers and it's pretty good. its hassle free. The SP changes, DDL changes everything is captured with a versioning.
So you can easily roll back to an older version.
The only drawback I found if you rename the table from SSMS it's not capturing.
I think its raised in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have not implemeneted trigger so how can I know what all tables have already been modified. Trigger will be useful for me for future table modifications but how would I know the changes been done to earlier

Comment: @SpringLearner, AFAIK, yes you can't get the modifications done earlier. All you can get the changes before restart as mentioned by dbamex.